# Finding all span elements containing a certain text and class

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my HTML page I have a number of span tags with a class named "Tested". I need some jQuery code that finds all of these span elements with that class name and also contains span text of "TE" anywhere in the text. I would then like to change the color of the text to red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with filter and each

```
$('span.Tested').filter((index,obj) => $(obj).text().indexOf("TE")>=0  )
  .each((index,obj) => $(obj).css('color', 'red') );
```

Edited:

```
$('span.Tested').filter((index,obj) => $(obj).text().indexOf("TE")>=0  ).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: It's jQuery. You don't need the `.each()`  since `.filter()` returns a collection of Elements.